# What does the number mean in this apt-get error

Tags: installation, debian, package-management, apt-get

I don't understand if the dependency requirement says that version less than 2.33 is good and the package to be installed is 2.32 which is less than 2.33, everything looks fine, why still reporting this error?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: glib-networking (< 2.33.12) but 2.32.3-1 is to be installed
wine32:i386 : Breaks: libwine-bin:i386 (< 1.5.31-1) but 1.4.1-4 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it now.

5.2.1.3. Incompatibilities: the Breaks Field
The Breaks field has an effect similar to that of the Conflicts field, but with a special meaning. It signals that the installation of a package will “break” another package (or particular versions of it). In general, this incompatibility between two packages is transitory, and the Breaks relationship specifically refers to the incompatible versions.
dpkg will refuse to install a package that breaks an already installed package, and apt-get will try to resolve the problem by updating the package that would be broken to a newer version (which is assumed to be fixed and, thus, compatible again).
This type of situation may occur in the case of updates without backwards compatibility: this is the case if the new version no longer functions with the older version, and causes a malfunction in another program without making special provisions. The Breaks field prevents the user from running into these problems.